# How to stop soft keyboard appear by default in android

Tags: java, android

I am writing an android application with two EditText on the main activity. My problem is that once the main activity starts the soft keyboad automatically appears. I want the soft keyboard to appear only when the user clicks on the EditText component. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11732587/1436931

Comment: Please try to do more research yourself before asking on so. -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity, in your `onCreate` method, put the following

```
edittext.setFocused(false);
```

And then afterwards (in a different method, maybe an `onClickListener` for your edittext) put

```
edittext.setFocused(true);
```

Also you could put the below line in you manifest, in the the activity section, just below the `android:name` attribute

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text_id"
      ..
      android:focusable="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to manage the inpt events , take a look on this part : 
==> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html